# PHP CodeIgniter How to set Https(SSL) on certain page as a subdomain(ex mypage.domain.com)?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, ssl

I'm setting our domain as SSL(https).

But Akamai SSL plan for 'www.mydomain.com' is super expensive, Cause we serve all over the world.

So, we got a SSL subdomain 'https secure.example.com' and want to cover just for certain pages like 'login', 'mypage' , 'register page' and etc.

For the first, I set redirection to 'https://secure.example.com' when user visit the pages. (Inverse case, redirect to 'http://www.example.com')

But between www and subdomain can't share session.

How to set sharing session between www and subdomain?
I googled and found below.

```
$config['cookie_prefix'] = "mydomain_";
$config['cookie_domain'] = ".mydomain.in";
$config['cookie_path'] = "/";
$config['cookie_secure'] = FALSE;
```

but this solution make all subdomains share session.
we also couple of subdomain, and don't want to share session all over those subdomains, just secure.example.com.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Is really necessary get data from cookies on unsecure pages and this data will be usefull if the user go to the secure page?